# Problems with catching event form button press in C#

Tags: c#, forms, events, button, calculator

I'm new to C#.net. As I said, I have problem with catching event form button press.
This is my project: [Calculator.rar](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=9D16E09C75CB8BCA!11973&authkey=!AGJY97B9nlB0Y_Y&ithint=file%2Crar)

I am writting a calculator program and worked fine when i press button in form by mouse. But i want to use keyboard to enter numbers and it will return the result when i press Enter. So i used this:

```
private void FrmCalculator_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.KeyCode)
        {
            /*case Keys.Enter:
                btnBang_Click(new object(), new EventArgs());
                break;*/
            case Keys.Back:
                btnBackSpace_Click(new object(), new EventArgs());
                break;
            case Keys.Escape:
                btnReset_Click(new object(), new EventArgs());
                break;
        }
    }
```

and this:

```
private void FrmCalculator_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.KeyChar)
        {
            case '0':
                btn0_Click(new object(), new EventArgs());
                break;
            case '1':
                btn1_Click(new object(), new EventArgs());
                break;
            case '2':
                btn2_Click(new object(), new EventArgs());
                break;
            case '3':
                btn3_Click(new object(), new EventArgs());
                break;
            case '4':
                btn4_Click(new object(), new EventArgs());
                break;
            case '5':
                btn5_Click(new object(), new EventArgs());
                break;
            case '6':
                btn6_Click(new object(), new EventArgs());
                break;
            case '7':
                btn7_Click(new object(), new EventArgs());
                break;
            case '8':
                btn8_Click(new object(), new EventArgs());
                break;
            case '9':
                btn9_Click(new object(), new EventArgs());
                break;
            case '.':
                btnCham_Click(new object(), new EventArgs());
                break;
            case '+':
                btnCong_Click(new object(), new EventArgs());
                break;
            case '-':
                btnTru_Click(new object(), new EventArgs());
                break;
            case '*':
                btnNhan_Click(new object(), new EventArgs());
                break;
            case '/':
                btnChia_Click(new object(), new EventArgs());
                break;
        }
    }
```

It worked perfectly with button 1,2,3..ect. But if i press Enter instead of button = in form, the result will wrong!
Anyone can explain my problem and tell me how to solve it? Thanks very much!

PS: Sorry for my bad english please :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this way
first set Active control in form Load Event by this code

```
this.ActiveControl = txtDuLieu;
```

then add follow case in `FrmCalculator_KeyPress` method

```
case    ((char) (13)):
                    //Call your Event
                    break;
```

13 is EnterKey Ascii code